# spring cloud eureka UnknownHostException

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

Here is my eureka yml:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eureka
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka:8761/eureka/
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

And here is my zuul server yml eureka part:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka:8761/eureka/
```

When I registry the zuul server to eureka , it throws 
 `java.net.UnknownHostException: eureka`

If I change the zuul server yml to `defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/`
it would be deployed successfully,
so how can I use 'eureka' host replace localhost, can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you have a hostname called eureka?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding "127.0.0.1  eureka" to your hosts file.

Answer (score 1):

> If I change the zuul server yml to defaultZone:
>   http://localhost:8761/eureka/ it would be deployed successfully

Which means you have deployed Eureka server on your local machine. If you want to use `eureka` as hostname, you can [change your hostname](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87665/how-do-i-change-the-hostname-without-a-restart) to `eureka`.

Or may be you meant to use `${eureka.hostname}`. The [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__service_discovery_eureka_clients.html#_registering_a_secure_application) says;

> ${eureka.hostname} is a native placeholder only available in later
>   versions of Eureka. You could achieve the same thing with Spring
>   placeholders as well, e.g. using ${eureka.instance.hostName}